# Keeping code clean with a WYSIWYG rich text editor

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, wysiwyg

I'm tinkering with making a WYSIWYG editor. And yes, I'm fully aware of `execCommand()`, but I don't like [how messy, and inconsistent it can get](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html).

**Note:** This is not a question of how to get it to work, as other questions are, but rather how to keep the end result clean.

The next best option seems to be `window.getSelection()`, which works great, until I hit a situation like this:

```
<p id="para" contenteditable="true">
A bit of <b>a</b> <span class="blackColor">lon</span><i>ger</i> sentence.
</p>
```

Which to the user gives

> A bit of **a** lon*ger* sentence

So, this is what I've come up with, so far to bold something:

```
function bold(){
    var box = document.getElementById("para");
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if(sel.rangeCount < 1) return;

    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    if(!validSelection(range.startContainer, box) || !validSelection(range.endContainer, box)){
        return;
    }

    // Get what we need from the first element
    var data = range.extractContents();

    for(var i = 0; i < data.childNodes.length; ++i){
        var b = document.createElement('b');
        b.innerHTML = data.childNodes[0].textContent;
        data.appendChild(b);
        data.removeChild(data.firstChild);
    }

    range.extractContents();
    range.insertNode(data);   
}
```

It works, but it can get messy, very, very fast.

```
<p id="para" contenteditable="true">
    A <b>b</b><b>it</b><b></b> of <b>a</b> <span class="blackColor">lon</span><i>ger</i> sentence.
</p>
```

That's after calling `bold()` for "it" and then "bit".

If I call it over multiple elements, such as, "of a long"

```
<p id="para" contenteditable="true">
A bit <b>of </b><b>a</b><b> </b><b>lon</b><b>g</b><i>er</i> sentence.
</p>
```

That's seems much worse than `execCommand()`, but I'd still like to do this in a clean manner. What is the proper way to do this to where I won't have extremely messy code once all is said and done? Also, I do realize that other formatting has been lost from the original. Something I'm working on, but my main thing is keeping it clean right now.

I've noticed in the inspector that if I hit [Ctrl] + B, and and then undo, things break up into multiple text nodes, but stay not-so-messy in the actual code. However, that only works for bold, italics, and underline, and I'd like to implement a few more things.

As an end note, I am open to just cleaning up `execCommand()`, but if I can instead code it myself... well... I like coding. :)

Thanks.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Johan, I'm not asking for my code to be reviewed, I'm asking how to accomplish something. Please read the question.